# Preencher array com retorno de array

Tags: javascript

Eu faço uma requisição, onde busca dados de uma requisição, onde ele me retorna as "Areas" e salvo dentro de um array.
Faço um iterador para buscar os "tópicos" referentes a aquela "Area", queria colocar esse retorno, dentro do mesmo array, porém com uma posição nova, com os dados referentes as "Áreas"

**Retorno da primeira requisição**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Retorno das requisições que são geradas a partir da primeira requisição**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O objetivo é colocar esses segundos dados dentro do primeiro Array

Apareceria algo do tipo

```
id: 1
parent_id: 0
product_id: 1
name: "Clínica Médica"
photo: "http://simsave.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/public/topics/{size}/1565627445064.jpg"
description: null
type: [""]
medicine: 1
nursing: 0
nursing_tech: 0 
"dados":Array([0..9]) // Aqui com os valores do primeiro retorno


this.api.Get("../topic/product/listProducts?product_id=" + id).subscribe((res: any) => {
      let topics = [res.length];

        for(let i:number = 0; i < res.length; i++){
          topics[i] = res[i];
          this.api.Get("../topic/parent/listProductParent?parent_id=" + topics[i].id).subscribe((ret: any) => {
              topics[i].push(ret);
          });
        }
      console.log(topics);
    });
```

Comment: por favor coloque o resultado da requisição, não temos acesso a essa API, então não conseguimos escrever uma resposta sobre algo que não sabemos.

Comment: Coloquei aqui agora @Paz

Comment: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas - **Postar código como imagem**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Comment: Se entendi bem, você faz uma requisição que retorna um array de objetos.
Dentro desse objetos você quer usar o id de cada um para pegar outros objetos que contenham a propriedade parent_id igual o id desses objetos.
E dentro do objeto "pai" você quer preencher uma propriedade dados com os objetos da segunda requisição que tenham parent_id igual ao id.

Comment: siim, isso, confuso mas é isso

Comment: @Paz é exatamente isso

Comment: na verdade, não e bem isso que tu respondeu, vamos abrir um chat?

Comment: pode abrir o chat...

Comment: beleza, vou abrir

Comment: Eu abri uma sala mas não consegui te adicionar @Paz

Comment: passe o link por favor

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104381/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-paz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue um exemplo de como implementar no seu caso, você deve usar o for para colocar os dados dos filhos dentro da propriedade `dados` enquanto ocorre a iteração (não testado, pois não possuo acesso a sua API).

```js
var chamada_1;

this.api.Get("../topic/product/listProducts?product_id=" + id).subscribe((res: any) => {
      let topics = [res.length];
      chamada_1 = res;
        for(let i:number = 0; i < res.length; i++){
          topics[i] = res[i];
          this.api.Get("../topic/parent/listProductParent?parent_id=" + topics[i].id).subscribe((ret: any) => {
              chamada_1[i]["dados"] = ret; //aqui insiro os dados que tem o parent_id correspondente com o id do pai
              
          });
        }
      console.log(chamada_1);
    });
```